# MS SQL Limit option not working

Tags: sql-server, go, go-gorm

I have built a query with a few condition statements added on. They all work fine, but when I type to had a limit option, I only get errors.

So I am using go 1.10 with Gorm and the Gin framework. This is my current working code,

```
qb := myDB.Table("table").Select("xx, xxx, xxx, xxx")

rows, err := qb.Rows()

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

defer myDB.Close()

return rows
```

This is all working, but when I add a limit anywhere, e.g. before the table or after, I tried both but did not really think it made a difference? For example,

```
qb := myDB.Table("table").Limit(3).Select("xx, xxx, xxx, xxx")
```

Now I know MS SQL does not use limit but uses TOP within the select statement (forgive me if that is not the only use case, still not used MS SQL much).

The error I get back is,

```
mssql: Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.
```

Now I have found the following on Gorm's GitHub, https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/1205

They have a work around but that will not work for me. The guy has also posted an updated function to correct the issue. However, I am not sure how I could update the code in a third party lib. Also this was posted in 2016, so not sure if that code has already been added to the Gorm code base.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `Order By` to use OFFSET + FETCH in the generated SQL sent to SQL Server, which would be added by your ORM

> ...the following conditions must be met:
>
> ...
>
> The ORDER BY clause contains a column or combination of columns that
>   are guaranteed to be unique.

How GORM does it, I don't know

Comment: Just tried that, with Gorm's order after the limit option. But still getting same error

Comment: Before I was using Gorm, I had this working with pure SQL. So I know it works with Go + MS SQL but just cant seem to get it to work with Gorm :(

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the Gorm framework.  It should know how to properly construct a query.  One workaround may be to create a stored procedure to do the query.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as an answer, i am guesting its more a work around and please let me know if this not recommend for any reason.

My working solution,

```
qb := myDB.Table("table").Select("TOP(?) xx, xxx, xxx, xxx", 3)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing similar issue. Got it working by adding .Order like this:

```
qb := db.Table("tableName").Order("columnName").Limit(2).Select("col1, col2")
```

Comment: At the time, I am sure I tried this and it did not work, must have been something I was also doing or maybe I was doing Limit then Order and that might have a knock on effect. But thanks for posting your soultion